# C# Extension Methods

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, extension-methods, ienumerable

I'm currently trying to write an extension method, but it doesn't seem to be operating as intended.  Before we delve too much deeper, here's the code I have:

```
 public static void Remove<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
 {
     var items = source.Where(predicate);

     source = source.Where(t => !items.Contains(t));
 }
```

The desire is that I can call this extension method on any IEnumerable and all items matching the predicate are then removed from the collection.  I'm tired of iterating through collections to find the items that match and then removing them one at a time to avoid altering the collection while enumerating through it...

Anyway... When I step through the code, everything seems to work.  Before existing the method, the `source` has the correct number of items removed.  However, when I return to the calling code all of the items still exist in my original IEnumerable object.  Any tips?

Thanks in advance,
Sonny

Comment: One more thing... the Contains method is another extension method I wrote (which does work as intended).

Comment: BTW, didn't know if you were aware of it or not, but LINQ does have a Contains method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357185.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can't do that the way you have originally written it, you are taking a reference variable (`source`) and making it refer to a new instance.  This modifies the local reference `source` and not the original argument passed in.

Keep in mind for reference types in C#, the default parameter passing scheme is pass by value (where the value being passed is a reference).

Let's say you pass in a variable `x` to this method, which refers to the original list and that list lives at theoretical location 1000, this means that source is a new reference to the original list living at location 1000.

Now when you say:

```
source = source.Where(....);
```

You are assigning `source` to a new list (say at location 2000), but that only affects what `source` points to and not the `x` you passed in.

To fix this as an extension method, you would really want to `return` the new sequence instead:

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> Remove<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
 {
     if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
     if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");

     // you can also collapse your logic to returning the opposite result of your predicate
     return source.Where(x => !predicate(x));
 }
```

This is all assuming you want to keep it totally generic to `IEnumerable<T>` as you asked in your question.  Obviously as also pointed out in other examples if you only care about `List<T>` there is a baked-in `RemoveAll()` method.

Comment: In fact, I'd probably name it WhereNot() instead of Remove() since Remove() implies it mutates the original list, whereas WhereNot() has a nice parallel sound to Where()...

Comment: Good point about the naming. I would argue that this method is superfluous in its current form, since now it's just a `Where()` wrapper (with free `!`!)

Comment: It is, but it COULD be useful if you just wanted to pass a method group as a predicate instead of a lambda negating the method group to Where().  It is rather trivial, granted, but I could see someone wanting to say:  `WhereNot(MyPredicateMethod)` instead of `Where(x => !MyPredicateMethod(x))`

Comment: Interesting point. I personally try to lambdafy my LINQ expressions, but this would work around that need.

Comment: Hah, I like the term "lambdafy" you should TM that :-)

Answer (score 4):

This kind of extension should be implemented by *returning* a new sequence. That way you can integrate into a chain of sequence operations:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Remove<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return source.Where(t => !predicate(t));
}

var query = mySequence.Select(x => x.Y).Remove(x => x == 2).Select(x => 2*x);
```

Now the method is nothing but a wrapper around `Where()`, which obviously isn't helpful. You might consider getting rid of it.

If you want to actually update the underlying collection (assuming that even exists) then you can't do it this way, since `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't provide any way to alter its contents. You would have to do something like:

```
var myNewList = new List<int>(oldList.Remove(x => x == 2));
```

Finally, if you *are* working with `List<T>`, you can use the `RemoveAll()` method to actually remove items from the list:

```
int numberOfItemsRemoved = myList.RemoveAll(x => x == 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this there's a useful List.RemoveAll(Predicate match) method which I think is designed for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx

so just use this on the list which you have.

```
source.RemoveAll(t => !items.Contains(t))
```

or your extension method returns you the required enumerable and you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

This is because IEnumerable is immutable
You have to return another sequence from your Remove method for this to work:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Remove<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
   var items = source.Where(predicate);

   return source.Where(t => !items.Contains(t));
}
```